# The characters entered through keyboard gets converted to equivalent ASCII code & stored on RAM in the binary form.How it happens

Tags: cpu-architecture

I got this question from [here](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/16596) Though they have answered but I want to get a clear and more deeper accurate answer.
Ok what I am looking for is how this mapping actually happens in the background. Any good link will also be useful since after placing this question directly in google, I didnot get any suitable answer.

Thanks for the response.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague given the answers already on the link provided. Please be specific.

Comment: So if you mean that the first answer in that site is correct then i will delete this question.